# ODBC connection to Cisco UCCX

Tags: sql, odbc, sql-server-2008-r2

I followed [this guide](https://amrgaber.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/create-an-odbc-connection-to-connect-to-cisco-uccx-server/) to successfully create an ODBC connection to UCCX, but using the 32bit driver. I need to use the 64bit driver and the GUI changed dramatically.

[My 64 bit ODBC settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnqfJ.png)

Below is the error I receive when trying to connect:

> SQL30081N A communication error has been
> detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication
> API being used: "SOCKETS". Location where the error was detected:
> "192.168.1.200". Communication function detecting the error: "recv".
> Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0". SQLSTATE=08001

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide is for the IBM ODBC Driver for Informix.

Your configuration screenshot is from the IBM ODBC Driver for DB2.

You need to use an ODBC Driver for Informix, as shown in the guide...

Comment: I see, I downloaded the IBM Informix drivers, but it looks like I ran the "IBM Data Server Driver Package" install rather than the install.exe that installs both of them. Thanks again TallTed, you are awesome.

Comment: Thanks Luis and Ted. I solved the initial issue with your guys help. One final question - I have a data source configured and it's testing successful. When I go into Report Builder and try to create a dataset using the datasource though, I get the below error:
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
I think SSRS is 64bit and Report Builder is 32bit. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Possibly, but you would usually get an error about "architecture mismatch" in that case. Please read my company's articles on these subjects...  [ODBC on 64-bit Windows](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin), [SQL Server as ODBC client on 64-bit Windows](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin).

Comment: Comments are now echoing [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258718/ssrs-64bit-to-mandatory-32bit-odbc-cisco-uccx/39259379?noredirect=1#comment65893655_39259379)

Comment: Moved to new location:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280939/ssrs-issues-with-both-32bit-and-64bit-odbc-drivers